# How to get key events from a fullscreen OpenGL window?

Tags: c, macos, opengl

I am writing a simple app in C using the CGL functions in Mac OS X. CGL can create an OpenGL context that runs fullscreen, which is what I want. However, it steals focus from the terminal so I don't have any way of capturing key events. Since I am not using Cocoa, how would I get key events once the app goes fullscreen? I'd like to try to stay away from Cocoa because I need the app to be as portable as possible.

Answer (score 2):

> Since I am not using Cocoa, how would I get key events once the app goes fullscreen? I'd like to try to stay away from Cocoa because I need the app to be as portable as possible.

Then use a cross plattform framework like GLFW or SDL.

Comment: Thanks. Is there no way to capture key input from a fullscreen CGL application? I tried creating a Cocoa version of the same app, but I still can't seem to capture key input so long as terminal window is open. Is there no solution to this other than launching an NSWindow?

Comment: @Synthetix: Well, you'll have to use some OS dependent calls anyhow. OpenGL doesn't deal with user input, it only *draws* things.

Comment: Yep, I ended up using CGEventSourceKeyState. As far as I know, it's the only way to sniff keyboard input without having to resort to Cocoa and running the OpenGL loop in a separate thread.

Comment: Just a response to the suggestion about GLFW: I attempted to use GLFW and still had issues with key event handling, which did not seem to work out of the box.  I found the issue to be that one needs to package one's executable binary within an application bundle (i.e. a `.app` directory structure) before I could properly interact with it.  This information is already stated on the GLFW FAQ, but Google does not have the GLFW FAQ indexed nearly as well as Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Synthetix You can also use IOHIDManager to poll the keyboard, although I am not sure how that affects your threading decision.